# Why do I still get the desire results when not specifying the FIELDTERMINATOR here?

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I have the following CSV file:

```
Number,Letter
1,"A","G"
2,"B","H"
3,"C","I"
4,"D","J"
5,"E,F","K"
```

I uploaded the CSV file into my Azure storage account. I opened Azure Synapse and ran the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'taxi/raw/Sample.csv',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'nyc_taxidata',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        FIRSTROW=2,
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
        FIELDQUOTE = '"'
    )
    AS [result]
```

I get the following results:

[image]

Why does it work even though I did not use

```
FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset):

> **<bulk_options>**
>
> FIELDTERMINATOR ='field_terminator'
>
> Specifies the field terminator to be used. The default field terminator is a comma ("**,**").

So, as you didn't specify `FIELD_TERMINATOR` then a comma (`,`) was used, which is why it worked.